# Weird speeds of devices on WiFi router

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ipad, wifi

I am trying to make sense of the networking speeds reported by my wifi router.

This is what I see (added models and years):

[image: router]

Why am I seeing these numbers?

It is puzzling to me that the fastest device is a 2016 iPad, and the slowest is the iPhone 13 Pro. All Macs are Intel-based, just to complete the picture, although I don't think it could really have an impact.

Can anyone explain why I am looking at these speeds, which I expected to be inverted?

Comment: How close is each device to the router?

Comment: Also, might it be possible that the devices have throttled the WiFi chip for energy saving reasons? Not sure if it's possible at all.

Comment: I am at 5-6 feet from the router in the same room. Also how can I verify the throttling?

Comment: What happens to the other devices' speeds if you shut down (not sleep) your 2010 MBP and your printer?

Comment: It turns out I had a faulty wifi router, with the new one (802.11ac) the speeds are correct. I do not know how I could close the question, if anyone can, I'd appreciate it.